# how to mock (awaitable) System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EMCResponse> in c#

Tags: c#, task, nunit, moq

I am novice to C# and have been trying to mock an object of type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EMCResponse>` but could not succeed. Can anyone help me how to mock?

```
public class PEProcessor : IPEProcessor
{
    public PEProcessor(IService service)
    {
        _proxy = service;
        _emUpdate = new EMUpdate(service);
    }


    public void CreateAddress(string modelName, string version, string name, MType mType, Address address, EMRequest request)
    {
        var response = _proxy.EMCreateAsync(request); // should return object of type (awaitable) System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EMCResponse>
        address.Id = Convert.ToInt32(response.Result.CM[0].Code);
    }

}
```

I am mocking as below

```
[Fact]
public void RequestIsVerifiable()
{

    //Arrange
    var wcfMock = new Mock<IService>();

    // wcfMock.Setup(x => x.EMCreateAsync(It.IsAny<EMCreateRequest>())).ReturnAsync(??);

    //Act
    var peProcessor = new PEProcessor(wcfMock.Object);
    peProcessor.CreateAddress(MoqData.ModelName, MoqData.version, MoqData.name,
        MoqData.MType, MoqData.AddressesList(), MoqData.EMRequest);

    //Assert
    wcfMock.Verify(service => service.EMCreateAsync(It.IsAny<EMCreateRequest>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well how do you want the task to behave? If you want it to just be completed immediately, you can use `Task.FromResult(...)`.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to mock the task here; you only need to mock the *result* of the task - the task itself can just be pre-completed

Comment: I am expecting `response.Result.CM[0].Code` value to be exist but I am getting `response.Result` itself as null. So I am just thinking to moq the call with the data. But I have no idea how to do!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to setup the mock to return the expected result so that the test can be exercised as expected.

```
var response = new EMCResponse {
    //populate
};

wcfMock
    .Setup(x => x.EMCreateAsync(It.IsAny<EMCreateRequest>()))
    .ReturnAsync(response);
```

That said, If it is possible to refactor that code to be async all the way and not have to make blocking calls.

```
public class PEProcessor : IPEProcessor {
    public PEProcessor(IService service) {
        _proxy = service;
        _emUpdate = new EMUpdate(service);
    }    

    public async Task CreateAddress(string modelName, string version, string name, MType mType, Address address, EMRequest request) {
        var response = await _proxy.EMCreateAsync(request); // should return object of type (awaitable) System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EMCResponse>
        address.Id = Convert.ToInt32(response.CM[0].Code);
    }
}
```

The can be exercised  as follows

```
[Fact]
public async Task RequestIsVerifiable() {

    //Arrange
    var wcfMock = new Mock<IService>();

    var response = new EMCResponse {
        //populate
    };

    wcfMock
        .Setup(x => x.EMCreateAsync(It.IsAny<EMCreateRequest>()))
        .ReturnAsync(response);

    var peProcessor = new PEProcessor(wcfMock.Object);

    //Act        
    await peProcessor.CreateAddress(MoqData.ModelName, MoqData.version, MoqData.name,
        MoqData.MType, MoqData.AddressesList(), MoqData.EMRequest);

    //Assert
    wcfMock.Verify(service => service.EMCreateAsync(It.IsAny<EMCreateRequest>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just delay some result or execution to mock that something is being done asynchronously, you can just use:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);//5000 means 5 seconds.
```

or if you want to execute the task later on then you can do the following.

```
var obj = SomeFunctionAsync().AsTask(); // this will return a IAsyncOperation object.
//some lines of code.
var result = await obj; // and this line will actually execute the method asynchronosly and return the required value (if any).
```

Comment: But I am not getting the data as I am expecting. Can't I mock the call to return some object? Something like `when().thenReturn()` as in `Java`.